# Is it possible to combine two hosts into one Google Webmaster Tools dashboard?

Tags: web-hosting, google-search-console

I have a web site running under `www`. Recently, we added some functionality that had different hosting requirements, so we added a `ww2` hostname.

Is there any way to combine both hosts into one dashboard? There is different content running on the two servers, so I can't use the canonical link functionality. A typical session would have someone follow a link from `www` -> `ww2` -> `www`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `www` and `ww2` for the same domain name, like: `www.example.com` and `ww2.example.com`, then actually this is the same domain with two subdomains (both are technically considered subdomains of `example.com`).

Google Webmaster Tools categorizes links from subdomains as internal links and should display them as such under the same dashboard, as indicated in this [Google Webmaster Blog](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/08/reorganizing-internal-vs-external.html):

> Most people think of example.com and www.example.com as the same site
>   these days, so we’re changing it such that now, if you add
>   either example.com or www.example.com as a site, links from both the
>   www and non-www versions of the domain will be categorized as internal
>   links. We’ve also extended this idea to include other subdomains,
>   since many people who own a domain also own its subdomains—so links
>   from cats.example.com or pets.example.com will also be categorized as
>   internal links for www.example.com.

So if you have links from `www` to `ww2` and vice versa, links from both sites should be crawled and show up in your dashboard. You may want to add the `ww2` URL's to your sitemap for the `www` site however just to make sure.

Comment: using a root domain (example.com) and a host in the domain (www.example.com) is a different case that two hosts within a domain (www.example.com and ww2.example.com).  The first case generally serves the same content from both servers, and can be handled with the canonical link.  The second case (cats vs pets) are internal links, but you will still need to add each url to the webmaster tools separately, and they will not be sharing a dashboard.

Comment: As I wrote, `www.example.com` and `ww2.example.com` are subdomains of `example.com` and considered as [internal links](http://www.seroundtable.com/subdomains-google-webmaster-tools-13960.html), regardless of the content or what servers they're located on.

Comment: correct, but what I'm trying to do is combine two servers, both subdomains of example.com, into one dashboard.  I can't find a way to do that.

Comment: Links for both subdomains, regardless of what servers they're located on, should be crawled and included throughout your site dashboard reporting. Just make sure the links between `www` and `ww2` can be crawled by Googlebot, and include them inside one sitemap for `www.example.com` or `example.com`. Other than combined reporting, I'm not sure else what you're expecting to see(?)

Comment: @chris: I don't think you can do this. `www` and `ww2` will need to be added as two separate sites in GWT. @dan: Links from one subdomain to the other might be seen as internal, but that is not the question. The OP simply wants to monitor the reported data for both sites as one single entity within GWT, which is not possible IMO.

Comment: @w3d Providing the links can be crawled and in the sitemap, the data for both subdomains will be included within the single site reports. Waiting for the OP to indicate if something more was expected.